# Get all values (even the empty ones) from Redux Form on Submit

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, relay

I need to get an object with all the field values (even the empty ones) when submitting a redux-form based form, because I am [setting relay variables](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1493) and it seems I need to reset them all explicitly.

Currently values, and the selector `getFormValues` return an object with the values of only the fields that have a `value !== ""`, so I am forced to do a workaround such a selector of this kind:

```
const getAllValuesSelector = (state) => {
  const formName = "ExampleForm";
  const registeredFields = state.form[formName].registeredFields;
  return registeredFields.reduce((memo, field) =>
   ({ ...memo, [field.name]: getFormValues(formName, field.name) }), {});
};
```

Which is a bit complex, is there a simpler solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which is not very nice, is there a better alternative to this?

Not currently, no.